# jQuery replace div with clone

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a small js script that will replace the value of a td with the cloned value.

I made a fiddle to be more clear.

I want to click the More button of a table and then to replace the More with the cloned div '123'.
And I want that Less to be the last td of the last tr but I will look into that later.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('table').each(function(){
    var $table = $(this);
    var n = $(this).find( "tr:nth-child(4) td:visible" ).length;
    var c = $(this).find('tr:nth-child(3)').last().find('td:last').clone();
    $(this).find('tr:nth-child(3)').last().find('td:last').html(
      "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='more-countries-big'>More</a>"
      );
    var x = $( "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='more-countries-big'>More</a>");
    x.on('click', function(){
        $table.find('tr:nth-child(3)').last().find('td:last').html(c.html());
    });
  });
  $("table").each(function(){
    var $tr = $(this).find('tr');
    $tr.hide();
    $tr.eq(0).show();
    $tr.eq(1).show();
    $tr.eq(2).show();
  });

    $('a.more-countries-big').on('click',function(){
        var txt = $(".open-continents").is(':visible') ? 'More' : 'Less';
        $(this).parents('table').find('tbody tr').toggleClass('open-continents');
        $(this).parents('table').find('a.more-countries-big').text(txt);
    });

});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pt4158dg/)

Thank you

Comment: Will all the numbers be the same for a given table? If not, how do you know which is the cloned value?

Comment: you never used `n` anywhere, and also do not use `$` for your variables. anyway, your question is not too clean for me. how many times do you want to clone, and what?

Comment: I changed the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3yfbb3kw/ ... I want when I click More from first table to replace it with 123l ... not Less. When I click on second's table More button to replace the Less with 123z. I hope this will be more clear. Thank you

Comment: $(this).on('click', function(){
          $table.find('tr:nth-child(3)').last().find('td:last').html(c.html());
        })
This solve my problem.

Comment: your code looks way too complicated for what you wanna archive.. and this is javascript not php - its a bad practice to use $ in front of variables

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is here:
You can use like that :

```
    $('a.more-countries-big').on('click',function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('less')) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).text("More");
            $(this).parents("table").find("tr:last").remove();
        } else {
            var tds = $(this).parents("table").find("tr:last").html();
            $(this).parents("table").append("<tr>"+tds+"</tr>");
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).text("Less");
        }
     })
```

if you want to add more column use different link and respected event.